# Hp pavilion 15 battery consumed fast

Tags: charging

I have hp pavilion 15 gaming laptop
When I use it for playing the battery is consumed rapidly
So my questiin is how Could I use it without charging my battery or without battery ?
My battery is fixed with screws .

Comment: Laptop batteries have a finite lifecycle of 100 - 200 charge/discharge cycles, with each cycle depleting a tiny percentage of its charge capacity. You'll be able to see the charge capacity of the battery by entering the BIOS/UEFI firmware hardware diagnostics and selecting Battery, which will also show other battery metrics. Especially with gaming laptops, they really should always be plugged into a charger when in use, and especially when using the discrete GPU or using software requiring high CPU usage, as they're meant to be plugged in most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your computer while it is plugged into AC, and while the battery is charging.  That should work fine. This has worked for me.

You cannot disable or remove the battery on a decently modern machine and yours is screwed in place (as on c a couple of my laptops).

So you really should replace the battery - it appears to have died.

But you can use the computer until then. You should move swiftly, because the battery can fail to the point the computer thinks it does not have one and/or the charge could be insufficient to start the computer.

Separately, read up on battery threshold management so you can set this properly when you get a new battery.  I use a steady charge of 80% for always plugged in.

It is not a good idea to leave any laptop plugged into AC all the time at 100% as that kills the battery early. Battery Threshold Management is much better for longer battery life.